# "The caller does not have permission" when signing GCP storage file URL from AWS lambda

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, federated-identity, workload-identity

I am trying to sign URL in GCP storage from AWS EC2 or Lambda, I have generated a JSON file for permissions providing my AWS account ID and role which is given to EC2 or Lambda. When I call sign URL even with storage admin or owner permission I get: `Error: The caller does not have permission`.

I used the code provided by GCP documentation.

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage(); 
const options = {
  version: 'v4',
  action: 'read',
  expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
};
 // Get a v4 signed URL for reading the file
 const [url] = await storage
 .bucket(bucketName)
 .file(fileName)
 .getSignedUrl(options);
```

Can anybody tell me what did I miss? What is wrong?
Seems the pro

*** update.

I am creating a service account, granting this service account storage admin to my project, then creating pull in **Workload Identity Pools**, setting AWS and my AWS account ID, then granting access by my AWS identities matching role, downloading JSON, and putting environment variables - `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` - path to my JSON file and `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` - my project ID. How to correctly load that `clientLibraryConfig.json` file to run functions I need?

update ** 2

my clientLibraryConfig JSON has the following content..

```
{
  "type": "external_account",
  "audience": "..",
  "subject_token_type": "..",
  "service_account_impersonation_url": "..",
  "token_url": "..",
  "credential_source": {
    "environment_id": "aws1",
    "region_url": "..",
    "url": "..",
    "regional_cred_verification_url": ".."
  }
}
```

How can I generate an access token in node js SDK from this config file to access GCP storage from AWS ec2?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the Google storage SDK loaded your Google credentials correctly?

Comment: For that, I tried another function which worked properly. 
 const files = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles().catch(console.log);
 and I got the list of all files in my bucket.

Comment: That presumably lists objects. Do you have get/read permission on `fileName` with that bucket?

Comment: I added storage admin role and object admin role, but that did not help.

Comment: Do the credentials have "Service Account Token Creator" permission?

Comment: Thanks for comments, I have created service account, than pool from 
Workload Identity Federation, than granted access to aws my account by account id and role , I am new in GCP, I use aws , want to  sign gcp file url from aws ec2

Comment: I did not generate any key and put owner role to my service account.

Comment: Workload Identity Federation makes a huge difference. Include details on what you set up, the roles assigned to the identity, and the token (Access or Identity) that you are using. In summary, you are exchanging credentials from one Identity Provider for credentials from another (AWS -> GCP). Your code does not appear to use the federated credentials.

Comment: I am creating service account, Granting this service account storage admin  to my project, then creating pull in Workload Identity Pools, setting aws and my aws account id, then granting access by my aws identitis matching role, downloading json and putting environment variables  -  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS - path to my json file and GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT - my project id, getFiles function lists my files in gcp storage , but no permission to get signed url for any file.

Comment: Please update your question with details instead of in the comments. Workload Identity Federation does not use environment variables (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS). Your code does not appear to use the federated credentials. Search for my other answers on this topic. In other words, you must specify the token when creating a credentials class to specify to **Storage()**.

Comment: Thanks for your info that is already something, I will update it soon!

Comment: Review this Python library. I do not often code in nodejs but there should be an equivalent for JavaScript. Use the **from_file()** class method to create credentials.  https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/reference/google.auth.external_account.html Also review this document: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-workload-identity-federation

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up the following permissions for the IAM service account:

- Storage Object Creator: This is to create signed URLs.
- Service Account Token Creator role: This role enables impersonation
  of service accounts to create OAuth2 access tokens, sign blobs, or sign JWTs.

Also, you can try to run locally in GCP to sign the URL with the service account.

1. You can use an existing private key for a service account. The key can be in JSON or PKCS12 format.
2. Use the command `gsutil signurl` and pass the path to the private key from the previous step, along with the name of the bucket and object.

For example, if you use a key stored in the folder Desktop, the following command will generate a signed URL for users to view the object cat.jpegfor for 10 minutes.

```
gsutil signurl -d 10m Desktop/private-key.json gs://example-bucket/cat.jpeg
```

If successful, the response should look like this:

```
URL    HTTP Method    Expiration    Signed URL
gs://example-bucket/cat.jpeg GET 2018-10-26 15:19:52 https://storage.googleapis.
com/example-bucket/cat.jpeg?x-goog-signature=2d2a6f5055eb004b8690b9479883292ae74
50cdc15f17d7f99bc49b916f9e7429106ed7e5858ae6b4ab0bbbdb1a8ccc364dad3a0da2caebd308
87a70c5b2569d089ceb8afbde3eed4dff5116f0db5483998c175980991fe899fbd2cd8cb813b0016
5e8d56e0a8aa7b3d7a12ee1baa8400611040f05b50a1a8eab5ba223fe5375747748de950ec7a4dc5
0f8382a6ffd49941c42498d7daa703d9a414d4475154d0e7edaa92d4f2507d92c1f7e811a7cab64d
f68b5df4857589259d8d0bdb5dc752bdf07bd162d98ff2924f2e4a26fa6b3cede73ad5333c47d146
a21c2ab2d97115986a12c28ff37346d6c2ca83e5618ec8ad95632710b489b75c35697d781c38e&
x-goog-algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&x-goog-credential=example%40example-project.
iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20181026%2Fus%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&x-goog-date=
20201026T211942Z&x-goog-expires=3600&x-goog-signedheaders=host
```

The signed URL is the string that starts with https://storage.googleapis.com, and it is likely to span multiple lines. Anyone can use the URL to access the associated resource (in this case, cat.jpeg) during the designated time frame (in this case, 10 minutes).
So if this works locally, then you can start configuring Workload Identity Federation to impersonate your service account. In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation#aws), you will find a guide to deploy it.

To access resources from AWS using your Workload Identity Federation you will need to review if the following requirements have been already configured:

- The workload identity pool has been created.
- AWS has been added as an identity provider in the workload identity
  pool (The Google organization policy needs to allow federation from
  AWS).
- The permissions to impersonate a service account have been granted to the external account.

I will add this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation#aws) to configure the Workload Identity Federation.

Once the previous requirements have been completed, you will need to generate the service account credential, this file will only contain  non sensitive metadata in order to instruct the library on how to retrieve external subject tokens and exchange them for service accounts tokens, as you mentioned the file could be an config.json and could be generated  running the following command:

```
# Generate an AWS configuration file.
gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config \
    projects/$PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/$POOL_ID/providers/$AWS_PROVIDER_ID \
    --service-account $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL \
    --aws \
    --output-file /path/to/generated/config.json
```

Where the following variables need to be substituted:

- $PROJECT_NUMBER: The Google Cloud project number.
- $POOL_ID:The workload identity pool ID.
- $AWS_PROVIDER_ID: The AWS provider ID.
- $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL: The email of the service account to
  impersonate.

Once you generate the JSON credentials configuration file for your external identity, you can store the path at the  `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/config.json
```

So, with this, the library can automatically choose the right type of client and initialize the credential from the configuration file. Please note that the service account will also need the roles/browser when using external identities with Application Default Credentials in Node.js or you can pass the project ID to avoid the need to grant roles/browser to the service account as is shown in the bellow code:

```
async function main() {
  const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
  // Pass the project ID explicitly to avoid the need to grant `roles/browser` to the service account
  // or enable Cloud Resource Manager API on the project.
  projectId: 'CLOUD_RESOURCE_PROJECT_ID',
  });
  const client = await auth.getClient();
  const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();
  // List all buckets in a project.
  const url = `https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=${projectId}`;
  const res = await client.request({ url });
  console.log(res.data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my code works with generated private keys, but I have to use client library configuration file, with aws ec2 role federated identities, json file has keys like {"type": "external_account", "audience":"", "credential_source":""} etc.. I do not know how to generate token from that json file.